# Parsing UIX XML and converting it to Excel with appropriate headings

Tags: xml, parsing

I want to parse the following XML code and get the subvalues of each node tag under appropriate headings in an excel sheet
For example:
First node tag

```
<node index="0" text="" resource-id="" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" package="com.whatsapp" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,0][1080,1920]">
```

How do I achieve this
[image]

For the following XML

```
<node index="0" text="" resource-id="" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" package="com.whatsapp" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,0][1080,1920]">
<node index="0" text="" resource-id="" class="android.widget.LinearLayout" package="com.whatsapp" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,0][1080,1920]">
<node index="0" text="" resource-id="" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" package="com.whatsapp" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,0][1080,1920]">
<node index="0" text="" resource-id="com.whatsapp:id/action_bar_root" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" package="com.whatsapp" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,0][1080,1920]">
<node index="0" text="" resource-id="android:id/content" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" package="com.whatsapp" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,0][1080,1920]">
<node index="0" text="" resource-id="com.whatsapp:id/root_view" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" package="com.whatsapp" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,0][1080,1920]">
<node index="0" text="" resource-id="" class="android.widget.LinearLayout" package="com.whatsapp" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,0][1080,1920]">
<node index="0" text="" resource-id="android:id/content" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" package="com.whatsapp" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,66][1080,1920]">
<node index="1" text="" resource-id="com.whatsapp:id/pager_holder" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" package="com.whatsapp" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,66][1080,1920]">
<node index="0" text="" resource-id="com.whatsapp:id/pager" class="androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager" package="com.whatsapp" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" scrollable="true" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,66][1080,1920]">
<node index="1" text="" resource-id="android:id/content" class="android.widget.LinearLayout" package="com.whatsapp" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,66][1080,1920]">
<node index="0" text="" resource-id="android:id/list" class="android.widget.ListView" package="com.whatsapp" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="true" scrollable="true" long-clickable="true" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,220][1080,1920]">
<node index="0" text="" resource-id="" class="android.view.View" package="com.whatsapp" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,220][1080,352]"/>
<node index="2" text="" resource-id="com.whatsapp:id/contact_row_container" class="android.widget.RelativeLayout" package="com.whatsapp" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="true" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,354][1080,563]">
<node index="0" text="" resource-id="com.whatsapp:id/contact_selector" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" package="com.whatsapp" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="true" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,354][226,563]">
```

Solution in python would be preferable, others are also fine.
Thank you

Comment: What have you tried and where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: @DanielHaley I have searched everywhere and I'm not able to find any solution for parsing UIX XML files, tried Python XML parser and also directly importing into excel sheet, still not able to get the desired output